# bootstrap column push/pull is not working as expected

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the following design for small, medium and large screen sizes::

[image]

For extra small screens I want it as:

[image: (image here)]

Here is my code:

```css
.one {
  background-color: #00CCFF;
}
.two {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
.three {
  background-color: #99CCFF;
}
.four {
  background-color: #CCFF33;
}
.five {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}
.six {
  background-color: #996666;
}
.mytab {
  height: 50px;
}
.abc {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #090;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3 abc">ABC</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 one mytab">1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 two mytab">2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 three mytab">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 four mytab">4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 five mytab">5</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 six mytab">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

The above code only results in the correct layout for the extra small size. For all the other sizes, I get the following result:

[image: Capture-now (image here)]

I do not need the white space. There may be something I am doing incorrectly with push/pull. Any advice/code change suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: superb question buddy !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the `push` and `pull` classes to achieve your desired output. Make the following changes to CSS:

- On the **ABC** `div`, remove `.col-sm-push-3` and add `.pull-right` to `float` the `div` to the `right`
- On the parent `div` containing, **1**, **2** and **3**, remove `.col-sm-pull-9`
- On the parent `div` containing, **4**, **5** and **6**, remove `.col-sm-push-3`

```css
.one {
  background-color: #00CCFF;
}
.two {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
.three {
  background-color: #99CCFF;
}
.four {
  background-color: #CCFF33;
}
.five {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}
.six {
  background-color: #996666;
}
.mytab {
  height: 50px;
}
.abc {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #090;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 pull-right abc">ABC</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 one mytab">1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 two mytab">2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 three mytab">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 four mytab">4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 five mytab">5</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 six mytab">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Why is this happening?**

left floated elements should stack next to each other when there is enough space for them to fit. Although it appears that this should happen in your original example, it is deceptive because you have used relative positioning to move the boxes into the desired location.

In effect, the `div` containing **1**, **2** and **3** is actually at the right edge of the parent `div` (it appears at the left because it is pushed to the `left` by `25%`) so there is no room for the **4**, **5** and **6** `div` to fit and so it is pushed onto a new line.

Comment: must have option to accept both, but feel to go for this. Thanks a lot

Comment: @abc123 No problem. I've added an extra bit of info to explain why this is occurring, just in case you hit the problem again in the future.

Comment: appreciate your support

Answer (score 3):

You can use the float hack to occupy the space above. New class `.align-top` added with floating property. Alternatively, in-built `pull-right` class has the same property as the new class I added. It is better to use it.

```css
.one {
  background-color: #00CCFF;
}
.two {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
.three {
  background-color: #99CCFF;
}
.four {
  background-color: #CCFF33;
}
.five {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}
.six {
  background-color: #996666;
}
.mytab {
  height: 50px;
}
.abc {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #090;
}
/* Below class is equivalent to pull-right of Bootstrap builtin code */
.align-top {
  float: right !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3 abc">ABC</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 align-top pull-right">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 one mytab">1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 two mytab">2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 three mytab">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 four mytab">4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 five mytab">5</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 six mytab">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: or just use pull-right class which contains the same property: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css